# How do I make a higher order React component with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm trying to make a higher order component with Typescript, but I'm getting a type mismatch. I completely stripped it down, so it should just wrap the component, but still getting the error:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export function createPage<Props extends {}, ComponentType extends React.ComponentType<Props>>(
  Component: ComponentType
) {
  return class WrappedComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props}></Component>;
    }
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<ComponentType, PropsWithChildren>'.

It looks like `IntrinsicAttributes` can match nothing, but `LibraryManagedAttributes` is absolutely inscrutable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to provide a generic argument for the Props

```
export function createPage<Props>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
) {
  return class WrappedComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props}></Component>;
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOTAVwDsNgJG40iUYkAFFAOZIAPLxxgAzgD4AFKThwAwrkiMkjGAC5ExGADpl4NupgAVAJ5gRYiJKmkAlHADe8uERj0o7NABsUEhJwAOpQKGBWACaGqiZwVDyMkUHI6Poxxhqi4tIubgpESUhQMk6uChXuSJ7ecMIZahouei0wABbAEnpgOQC%20UsIA9A0mUgDc%20XC9btO9QA)

Comment: Thanks, that does it! Can you explain why this works?